# Una consulta me devuelve un array cuando debe devolverme un string

Tags: php, mysql

Estoy intentando sacar un dato de una base de datos a traves de otra tabla, pero cuando intento sacarla me manda un array con dos instancias con el mismo contenido:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En la sentencia se supone que solo debe de coger 1 instancia que es la que hay.

Donde llamo a la funcion:

```
Conexion::abrir_conexion();
$dni = RepositorioUsuario::obtener_dni(Conexion::obtener_conexion(), $_SESSION['nombre_usuario']);
var_dump($_SESSION['nombre_usuario']);
var_dump($dni);
```

Obtener_dni Aqui tengo la funcion con su consulta:

```
public static function obtener_dni($conexion, $nombre){
        $dni_x = true;

        if (isset($conexion)){
            try{
                $sql = "SELECT dni FROM usuarios WHERE nombre = :nombre";

                $sentencia = $conexion -> prepare($sql);

                $sentencia -> bindParam(':nombre', $nombre, PDO::PARAM_STR);

                $sentencia -> execute();

                $dni_x = $sentencia -> fetchAll();

                //Si establezco esta sentencia no se arregla
                //$dni_x = $dni_x[0];

            }catch(PDOException $ex){
                print 'ERROR'.$ex -> getMessage();
            }
        }
        return $dni_x;
    }
```

Aqui la base de datos ara ver que no hay otro nombre ni parecido:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Pues será que tienes dos registros con el mismo nombre y DNI.  Si quieres mostrar solo uno ponle un LIMIT 1 a la consulta o bien un `SELECT DISTINCT dni`

Comment: "SELECT DISTINCT dni FROM usuarios WHERE nombre = :nombre" He establecido esta consulta y sigue igual

Comment: Mas que en la consulta el problema debe de estar en otro sitio que no logro entender.

Comment: Ah, perdon, no me di cuenta de un detalle. Es cosa del [fetchAll](https://www.php.net/manual/es/pdostatement.fetchall.php), que por defecto usa un fetch_Style así: `El valor predeterminado es PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE (el cual por defecto es PDO::FETCH_BOTH). ` Que según leo dice: `devuelve un array indexado tanto por nombre de columna, como numéricamente con índice de base 0 tal como fue devuelto en el conjunto de resultados. `. Mírate las otras opciones en su ayuda o no uses el fetchAll si tan solo quieres un solo resultado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Llevava ya un tiempo buscando la solucio y me di cuenta de que me creaba varios arrays dentro de otro, la solucion la he sacado asi:

```
$dni_x = $sentencia -> fetchAll();

$dni_x = $dni_x[0];
$dni_x = $dni_x['dni'];
```

Comment: No hace falta que uses ambos indices (el indexado numéricamente y el asociativo). Con que hagas esa igualdad `$dni_x =` una vez es suficiente, porque al hacerlo dos es inutil pues la segunda sobreescribe la primera.